# iphone problem - UIKit precompile error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been working on a project for a few weeks now and today is the last day before it goes to client (typical).

For some reason Im suddenly getting the following error when building my project (sim or device), even though other projects build fine

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:61:42:
>   error:
>   UIKit/UIVideoEditorController.h: No
>   such file or directory

The last thing I was trying to do was use the UIMessage framework for email, but I have stripped that out!?!?

N.B I have checked and the .h file does appear to be in the same folder as the UIKit.h file

Comment: Just a lame suggestion: delete all contents of you build directory and restart XCode. Works sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the SDK and reregistered all the frameworks, I have no idea why I had to do that!

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew Mitchell wrote in the post [iOS SDK broken ever after reinstall UIKit and Foundation frameworks not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008800/ios-sdk-broken-ever-after-reinstall-uikit-and-foundation-frameworks-not-found):

"It was the "Framework Search Paths" option. Make sure this is empty if anyone has a similar problem." -> It works for me!