# UIKit/UIKit.h file not found - XCode 4.6.1 - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After I updated XCode to 4.6.1 version, when I open a project developed in the last Xcode version, it gives me an error on every ".h" class I have, in the `import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` line. The error I'm having is "UIKit/UIKit.h file not found". How can I solve this?

Comment: check Link Binary with Libraries in Build Phases. uikit.framework is not here probably. add it manually

Comment: @meth where is exactly that on Xcode? Sorry I'm not too experienced on this

Comment: At Targets->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries

Comment: @meth It is already there, the UIKit.framework. Do you know what else could be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Availability.h, UIKit.h, etc not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380186/availability-h-uikit-h-etc-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly need to re-add `UIKit` to your frameworks under `Build phases`.