# Getting 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found while importing from c++

Tags: qt

This is my .pro file

```html
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
TEMPLATE = app
# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    bridgingfile.cpp
ios {
    OBJECTIVE_SOURCES +=  ViewController.m
}

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
#QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

## Default rules for deployment.
#qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
#else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
#!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    bridgingfile.h \
    ViewController.h

DISTFILES += \
    ViewController.m
```

getting error like this when i import objective c file

```html
/Users/workspace/SimpleIOS/ViewController.h:9: error: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found
```

i am new to Qt programming,how can i achieve this.
please help me out .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIKit/UIKit.h file not found - XCode 4.6.1 - Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578595/uikit-uikit-h-file-not-found-xcode-4-6-1-objective-c)

Comment: you need to include the UIKit library

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add UIKit framework in the ios scope inside your pro file:

```
ios: {   LIBS += -framework UIKit   OBJECTIVE_SOURCES +=  ViewController.m }
```