# xCode 5 tabbed application not building on iPhone with iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, xcode5.0.1

I created a tabbed application with xCode 5.01, recently downloaded from Apple, and put nothing else in it. It runs fine on the simulator, but when I try to run it on my iPhone 4S, which has OS6 on it, the build fails with these errors:

1. UIKit/UIKit.h is not found.
2. The Prefix.pch file is not found.

I looked everywhere and changed the deployment target to 6.0, but it doesn't solve the issue. What's going on?

EDIT: also, following an advice, I deleted the UIKit framework, but when I tried to re-add it (as per the advice) it turns out it's not there.

EDIT 2: Reinstalling xCode solved the issue. Go figure.

Comment: What is a "tabbed application"?

Comment: One of the options for an application, when you go to create a new project. Instagram, for example, is a "tabbed application"

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. I don't think the app being a tabbed application has any effect for what you're experiencing. Can you give us a screenshot of the error message? And maybe copy and paste the full error log? Do you have the prefix.pch file in your project? Please give more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9481323/1091539

Comment: Thanks, @Mutawe, I reinstalled xCode and it works now. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall XCode 5, it is still quite buggy, also when renaming folders, this can cause corrupt data structure inside the project file.