# ParseKit.framework won't work, Foundation.h not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor, foundation, parsekit

I'm really stumped trying to get the ParseKit.framework ([this](http://parsekit.com/index.html)) to work in general, not even bothering to implement it till it runs the demo app that comes with it.

What happens is the compiler can't locate < Foundation/Foundation.h> or something, which I thought the header was in the linked framework.  Exact error: "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found."

Here's the code, just from the ParseKit_Prefix.pch:

```
    //
    // Prefix header for all source files of the 'ParseKit' target in the 'ParseKit' project.
    //
    #ifdef __OBJC__
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #endif
```

Nothing unusual about it, did I mess up the file paths some how? I've reinstalled Xcode, re-downloaded the ParseKit, and nothing is helping.  The suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380186/availability-h-uikit-h-etc-not-found) did nothing and it's not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008800/ios-sdk-broken-ever-after-reinstall-uikit-and-foundation-frameworks-not-found).  When I make a new project or use a different project and load the Foundation.framework and #import the header it works just fine.  If I unlink the framework I can't find it to re-link again.  Has anyone else had this kind of problem?  Did I download it wrong somewhere?  I have a very difficult time finding where exactly the Xcode UI links stuff, apple must get a kick out of frustrating people, so if anyone has anything they can think of please give me some feedback, I'm horribly confused right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I figured I would post the answer if anyone cared.  I guess Xcode indexed it wrong when I opened the ParseKit.xcodeproj or something, changed the Base SDK from 'Current OS X' to 'OS X 10.7'...... and then back and it worked just fine for whatever reason.  Why?  Not a clue in the world, but I'm content with it working.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new line before the #ifdef. It looks like you have accidentally edited the ParseKit_Prefix.pch. It should look like the following:

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'ParseKit' target in the 'ParseKit' project.
//
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just my bad in the code block posting it.  The file is correct, untampered with and freshly downloaded, I edited the question to reflect that.  Thanks for the feedback.